# How to calculate mean and standard deviation from specific rows and columns from a dataset and add results as new columns in the same dataset?

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

This is part of a large dataset I am working on:

```
    structure(list(L = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), S_1 = c("W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"Z"), `First _1` = c(8.5, 8, 8.8, 9, 8.5, 9.5, 8.8, 9, 9.3, 9.3
), Second_1 = c(5.8, 5, 6, 6, 5, 8, 8.2, 8.5, 8.3, 8), S_2 = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), First_2 = c(6.5, 
7, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 7.5, 8, 7.5, 7, 7), Second_2 = c(7, 6.5, 7, 7.2, 
6.3, 6.7, 7, 7, 6.8, 5.7)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = c("L", "S_1", "First _1", 
"Second_1", "S_2", "First_2", "Second_2"))
```

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of columns 'First_1', 'Second_1', 'First_2' and 'Second_2' from the lines of 1 to 5 and then 6 to 10.

This means that I want to add eight other columns into this dataset which should then look like this:

```
    structure(list(L = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), S_1 = c("W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"Z"), `First _1` = c(8.5, 8, 8.8, 9, 8.5, 9.5, 8.8, 9, 9.3, 9.3
), Second_1 = c(5.8, 5, 6, 6, 5, 8, 8.2, 8.5, 8.3, 8), S_2 = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), First_2 = c(6.5, 
7, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 7.5, 8, 7.5, 7, 7), Second_2 = c(7, 6.5, 7, 7.2, 
6.3, 6.7, 7, 7, 6.8, 5.7), Mean_S_1_First_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Mean_S_1_Second_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Mean_S_2_First_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Mean_S_2_Second_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SD_S_1_First_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SD_S_1_Second_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SD_S_2_First_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), SD_S_2_Second_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .Names = c("L", "S_1", "First _1", "Second_1", "S_2", 
"First_2", "Second_2", "Mean_S_1_First_1", "Mean_S_1_Second_1", 
"Mean_S_2_First_1", "Mean_S_2_Second_1", "SD_S_1_First_2", "SD_S_1_Second_2", 
"SD_S_2_First_2", "SD_S_2_Second_2"))
```

I have tried this command from another post:

```
dat$Mean_S_1_First_1 <- with (dat, ave(First_1, findInterval(L, c(1:5)), FUN= mean) )
```

But the way I am writing this line is clearly wrong because it is not calculating the mean of the row interval (1:5) from column `First_1` and I am not sure how to easily add other **column names**, **row intervals** and the function '**standard deviation**' in this line of command.

The error message I get from running the command above is

```
Error in split(x, g) : object 'First_1' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In findInterval(L, c(1:5)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can anyone help this R beginner resolve this problem that I have been working on for few days already?

Cheers,

ps. Please do not be too harsh on your response to this question as I am truly trying to explain what I want and the problems I have encountered as clear as possible.

Comment: are you (i) grouping by L, S_1 and S_2 or (ii) in sequence of 5 data points (e.g, every 5 rows)?

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, I am

Comment: try something like `library(dplyr); tbldf %>% group_by(L, S_1, S_2) %>% mutate_each(funs(mean, sd))`

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12 I will try and let you know. The challenge now is installing this package in the R version 3.1.1. Good luck for me!

Comment: Uhuuuu. That works beautifully @chinsoon12. Cheers, mate!

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing to do is just

```
dat$Mean_S_1_First_1 <- mean(dat$First_1[1:5])
```

and so on for your other 8 columns. If this seems inefficient... well, you've already spent days on this so how inefficient can it be?

A way to do it for all 4 columns would be

```
result <- aggregate(dat, list(dat$L), FUN= mean)
```

You can then put result into your new columns as desired. This is assuming you're happy to use the L column to split your data by.

Another way would be with dplyr. You'll need to get rid of the spaces in your column names first. Then do:

```
dat %>% group_by(L) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = funs(mean= mean))
```

and tweak the column names. But note that this doesn't do quite what you want - it puts the means for  rows 1:5 and 6:10 in those rows, rather than in separate columns.

All of which raises the real question: why are you trying to associate the mean of rows 1-5 with rows 6-10? What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: You are right @dash2 Next time I might just take one step at a time rather than spending so much time trying to find the most efficient way to find an answer. My goal is to see whether there is a difference in results after averaging five scores in comparison with averaging three scores after eliminating the highest and the lowest scores. I also need to see the distribution of these scores to see how spread they are around the mean so that I can investigate to what extent judge criteria and perceptions are uniformly distributed.